# React Native app not detected by Fabric

Tags: android, react-native, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I want to integrate Fabric in my react native application from https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric.
I have followed the instructions provided in its documentation:

1. Installed the Fabric plugin in the Android Studio, created personal account in `fabrio.io`.
2. Installed `react-native-fabric` through `npm`.
3. Edited `android/settings.gradle`
4. Edited `android/app/build.gradle`
5. Edited `MainApplication.java` in the application class since my react native version is `0.41.2`. Please look below:

   `@Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
       SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
   }`

In my login screen I just wanted to test crash the app using `Crashlytics.crash();` of course I also initialized it globally with:

```
var Fabric = require('react-native-fabric'); 
var { Crashlytics } = Fabric;
```

Now the problem comes in, I'm now in login screen and when I pressed the Login button I encountered similar problem found [here](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric/issues/99). Yet from what I understood in the author's reply, I configured it properly. But I want to crash it, not prompted by red error. What I did was to make a release build, and it successfully crashed when I pressed the button. So does this mean, I can only test Crashlytics with the release build?

This is ,y analysis, correct me if I'm wrong:

> Since the Fabric plugin is installed in the Android Studio and it is configured in the native code, the React Native layer (codes) are not detected by Fabric.

So my problems are:

1. Is it correct to assume that I can't use or test Crashlytics with Debug mode? If not, did I miss any configuration?
2. Fabric plugin in my Android Studio can't detect my app even though I have added `android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I'm stuck in the `Launch your app!` stage from the Fabric plugin.
3. Now if I go to https://fabric.io/dashboard, I'm stuck with the Launch your app screen, also. I will be redirected to https://fabric.io/onboard.

Can anyone shed light on this? Or has anyone encountered these? Please let me know.

Comment: Vadim is it solve?

Comment: Even I worked with native proejct, java, I could see exact same issue and get stuck.